# A simple chess engine in Haskell

Tags: haskell, chess

This is my first Haskell project so I don't really have a good feel for what makes Haskell code clean, so they'll be lots of things that can be improved.

Things I have a gut feeling are bad design:

pieceAt on line 194 throws an error when it's called on an empty square. My reasoning was that it's
undefined behaviour and means I've made a mistake when programming it. Analogous to an assertionError 
in Java.

When pattern matching with moves on line 117, only the pawn uses the board team and pos arguments. 
This is definitely not a great way to handle pawn behaviour, but I can't think of a better way to do 
it as pawns are tricky to program.

Edit: In case anyone is confused my program does work, or at the very least seems to be able to play chess half-decently. I always check that the square is filled before calling pieceAt

```
import Data.Char

type Board = [[Square]] 
type Move = (Int, Int)
type Pos = (Int, Int) 
data PieceType = Rook | Knight | Pawn | King | Queen | Bishop deriving (Eq)
data Square = Filled Piece | Empty deriving (Eq)
data Piece = Piece Team PieceType deriving (Eq)
data Team = Black | White deriving (Eq)
data GameTree = Leaf Int | Node [GameTree] deriving (Show)

--Get AI's choice of move
pickMove :: Board -> Team -> Board
pickMove board team = fst $ getOptimalMove (possibleBoards board team) team

--For all moves the AI could make, run minimax on them all and return the best one
getOptimalMove :: [Board] -> Team -> (Board, Int)
getOptimalMove boards team = foldl accumFunction (head boards, minBound) boards

                           where accumFunction = \acc n -> let currentValue = minimizer $ generateGameTree (otherTeam team) team n in
                                                  if (currentValue >= snd acc) then (n, currentValue) else acc

--For all moves the AI could make, return most optimal
maximizer :: GameTree -> Int
maximizer (Leaf value) = value
maximizer (Node xs) = maximum $ map minimizer xs

--For all moves the opposing team could make, return least optimal for the AI
minimizer :: GameTree -> Int
minimizer (Leaf value) = value
minimizer (Node xs) = minimum $ map maximizer xs

--Generates a game tree
generateGameTree :: Team -> Team -> Board -> GameTree
generateGameTree = depthLimitedTree 1

--Helper function that generates game tree of a limited depth
depthLimitedTree :: Int -> Team -> Team -> Board -> GameTree
depthLimitedTree depth team originalTeam board | depth == 3 = Leaf $ evalBoard board originalTeam
                                               | otherwise  = Node $ map (depthLimitedTree (depth + 1) (otherTeam team) originalTeam) (possibleBoards board team)

--Generate all possible boards that can result from a teams move
possibleBoards :: Board -> Team -> [Board]
possibleBoards board team = foldl (\acc n -> acc ++ (genMoves board team n)) [] allMovesForTeam 

                            where allMovesForTeam = posTeam board team

--Generate all possible boards that can come from moving a piece at some position
genMoves :: Board -> Team -> Pos -> [Board]
genMoves board team pos = map (movePos board pos) listOfValidDestinations

                     where listOfValidDestinations = filter (isValidMove board pos) listOfDestinations
                           listOfDestinations = map (makeDestinationPos pos) (moves board team pos (extractType board pos))

--Return true if destination is on board and piece doesn't take its own team
isValidMove :: Board -> Pos -> Pos -> Bool
isValidMove board start destination = isOnBoard destination && not (takesOwnTeam board start destination) && isClearPath board path

                                      where path = drawPathKnightWrapper board start destination

-- Return true if the result of a move is a piece checking its own team
takesOwnTeam :: Board -> Pos -> Pos -> Bool
takesOwnTeam board start destination | squareAt board destination == Empty                      = False
                                     | extractTeam board start == extractTeam board destination = True
                                     | otherwise                                                = False 

-- Returns true if no pieces lie in the path
isClearPath :: Board -> [Pos] -> Bool
isClearPath _ [] = True
isClearPath board (x:xs) | squareAt board x /= Empty = False
                         | otherwise                 = isClearPath board xs


--Checks if piece path is being drawn from is a knight before drawing path
drawPathKnightWrapper :: Board -> Pos -> Pos -> [Pos]
drawPathKnightWrapper board start destination | extractType board start == Knight = []
                                              | otherwise                         = tail $ drawPath start destination

-- Given 2 positions, return all the positions that lie in between
drawPath :: Pos -> Pos -> [Pos]
drawPath (a, b) (x, y) | a == x && b == y = []
                       | otherwise        = (a, b):(drawPath (nextRow, nextCol) (x, y))

                       where nextRow = a + rowDirection (a, b) (x, y)
                             nextCol = b + colDirection (a, b) (x, y)

-- Return the directions that a movement takes, represented as a vector
movementType :: Pos -> Pos -> Move
movementType pos1 pos2 = (rowDirection pos1 pos2, colDirection pos1 pos2)

--Row component of movementType
rowDirection :: Pos -> Pos -> Int
rowDirection (a, _) (x, _) | x - a > 0  = 1
                           | x - a < 0  = -1
                           | x - a == 0 = 0 
--Column component of movementType
colDirection :: Pos -> Pos -> Int
colDirection (_, b) (_, y) | y - b > 0  = 1
                           | y - b < 0  = -1
                           | y - b == 0 = 0 

--Return true if position lies within dimensions of the board
isOnBoard :: Pos -> Bool
isOnBoard (row, col) = row >= 0 && row < 8 && col >= 0 && col < 8

--Given a position and a move, return the position that results from applying the move
makeDestinationPos :: Pos -> Move -> Pos
makeDestinationPos (x, y) (a, b) = (x + a, y + b)

--Given a piece type, return all the moves that it could make represented as vectors
moves :: Board -> Team -> Pos -> PieceType -> [Move]
moves board team pos Pawn = generatePawnMoves board team pos
moves _ _ _ King = [(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, -1), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
moves _ _ _ Knight = [(-2, -1), (-2, 1), (-1, -2), (-1, 2), (1, -2), (1, 2), (2, -1), (2, 1)]
moves _ _ _ Queen = forAllRangesInBoard [(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, -1), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1)] 1
moves _ _ _ Rook = forAllRangesInBoard [(-1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1), (1, 0)] 1
moves _ _ _ Bishop = forAllRangesInBoard [(-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1)] 1

--Return list of moves a pawn can make
generatePawnMoves :: Board -> Team -> Pos -> [Move]
generatePawnMoves board team pos = getFront board team pos 1 ++ getFront board team pos 2 ++ getDiagonal board team pos (-1) ++ getDiagonal board team pos 1

--Returns a move if there's no pieces in front to block it
getFront :: Board -> Team -> Pos -> Int -> [Move]
getFront board team (row, col) jumpSize | not $ isOnBoard posInFront         = []
                                        | squareAt board posInFront == Empty = [( getPawnDirection team * jumpSize, 0)]
                                        | otherwise                          = []

                                        where posInFront = (row + (getPawnDirection team) * jumpSize, col)

--Returns a move if there's an opposing teams piece to take
getDiagonal :: Board -> Team -> Pos -> Int -> [Move]
getDiagonal board team (row, col) modif | not $ isOnBoard diagonalPos               = []
                                        | squareAt board diagonalPos == Empty       = []
                                        | extractTeam board diagonalPos /= team     = [(getPawnDirection team, modif)]
                                        | otherwise                                 = []

                                        where diagonalPos = (row + (getPawnDirection team), col + modif)

--Return the direction a team's pawn will move in
getPawnDirection:: Team -> Int
getPawnDirection White = (-1)
getPawnDirection Black = 1

--Helper function for moves, scales a list of tuples to everything in range of a single move on a standard chess board
forAllRangesInBoard :: [Move] -> Int -> [Move]
forAllRangesInBoard list c | c == 8    = [] 
                           | otherwise =  movesForCurrentRange ++ restOfMoves

                             where movesForCurrentRange = map (tupleProduct c) list
                                   tupleProduct = (\mul tuple -> (fst tuple * mul, snd tuple * mul))
                                   restOfMoves = forAllRangesInBoard list (c + 1)

--Given a board and a team, return all positions in the board that have a piece of that team
posTeam :: Board -> Team -> [Pos]
posTeam board team = posTeamIter board team 0 0

--Helper function for posTeam
posTeamIter :: Board -> Team -> Int -> Int -> [Pos]
posTeamIter board team row col | squareAt board (row, col) == Empty         = recursiveCase
                               | extractTeam board (row, col) == team       = (row, col):recursiveCase
                               | otherwise                                  = recursiveCase

                                 where recursiveCase | row == 7 && col == 7 = []
                                                     | col == 7             = posTeamIter board team (row + 1) 0
                                                     | otherwise            = posTeamIter board team row (col + 1)

--Given 2 positions, move whatever is at the first position to the second position
movePos :: Board -> Pos -> Pos -> Board
movePos board from to = replaceEndSquare

          where removeStartPiece = replaceSquare board from Empty
                replaceEndSquare = replaceSquare removeStartPiece to (squareAt board from)

--Given a position and a square, replace whatever is at that position with the square that came as an argument
replaceSquare :: Board -> Pos -> Square -> Board
replaceSquare xs (row, col) square = replaceElem row replacedRow xs

                                              where pickRow = xs !! row
                                                    replacedRow = replaceElem col square pickRow

--Given a position, return the square that resides there. Only intended to be called if there's actually a piece
squareAt :: Board -> Pos -> Square
squareAt xs (row, col) = (xs !! row) !! col

-- Gets the piece that resides at a square. Throws an error if you try to get the piece of an empty square
pieceAt :: Square -> Piece
pieceAt Empty = error "Only intended to be called if there's actually a piece there"
pieceAt (Filled piece) = piece

getType :: Piece -> PieceType
getType (Piece _ pieceType) = pieceType

getTeam :: Piece -> Team
getTeam (Piece team _) = team

-- Given a position, return the team of the piece residing there. Throws an error if called for an empty square
extractTeam :: Board -> Pos -> Team
extractTeam board = getTeam . pieceAt . (squareAt board)

-- Given a position, return the type of the piece residing there. Throws an error if called for an empty square
extractType :: Board -> Pos -> PieceType
extractType board = getType . pieceAt . (squareAt board) 

otherTeam :: Team -> Team
otherTeam Black = White
otherTeam White = Black

--Heuristic value for all pieces in the board
evalBoard :: Board -> Team -> Int
evalBoard [] _ = 0
evalBoard (x:xs) team = evalRow x team + evalBoard xs team

--Helper function for evalRow, heuristic value of all pieces in a row
evalRow :: [Square] -> Team -> Int
evalRow [] _ = 0
evalRow (x:xs) team = valueSquare x team + evalRow xs team

--Helper function for evalRow, heuristic value of a square with team taken into account
valueSquare :: Square -> Team -> Int
valueSquare Empty _ = 0
valueSquare (Filled piece) team | getTeam piece == team = valuePieceType $ getType piece
                                | otherwise             = (-1) * (valuePieceType $ getType piece) 

--Helper function for valueSquare, heuristic value of a piece without team taken into account
valuePieceType :: PieceType -> Int
valuePieceType Pawn = 10
valuePieceType Knight = 30
valuePieceType Bishop = 40
valuePieceType Rook = 60
valuePieceType Queen = 100
valuePieceType King = 1000

-- The starting board for a game of chess
initBoard :: Board
initBoard = ([firstRow] ++ [secondRow] ++ middle ++ [secondLastRow] ++ [lastRow])

          where firstRow = map Filled $ map (Piece Black) [Rook, Knight, Bishop, King, Queen, Bishop, Knight, Rook]
                secondRow = replicate 8 (Filled $ Piece Black Pawn)
                middle = replicate 4 (replicate 8 Empty)
                secondLastRow = replicate 8 (Filled $ Piece White Pawn)
                lastRow = map Filled $ map (Piece White) [Rook, Knight, Bishop, King, Queen, Bishop, Knight, Rook]

--Returns string representation of a board. Note: Use putStrLn to render the line breaks properly
boardString :: Board -> String
boardString []  = ""
boardString (x:xs) = rowString x ++ (boardString xs)

--Helper function for boardString, returns string representation of a row
rowString :: [Square] -> String
rowString [] = "\n"
rowString (x:xs) = show x ++ rowString xs

instance Show Square where
    show Empty = "-"
    show (Filled piece) = show piece

instance Show Piece where
    show (Piece Black pieceType) = toLowerString $ show pieceType
    show (Piece White pieceType) = show pieceType

instance Show PieceType where
    show Rook = "R"
    show King = "K"
    show Pawn = "P"
    show Queen = "Q"
    show Bishop = "B"
    show Knight = "N"

--Generic Helper functions -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
toLowerString :: String -> String
toLowerString = map toLower 

--Given a list, an index and an element, replace the index of that list with the element. Indexing starts at 0
replaceElem :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
replaceElem _ _ [] = []
replaceElem counter elem (x:xs) | counter == 0 = elem:recursiveCase
                                | otherwise    =  x:recursiveCase

                                  where recursiveCase = replaceElem (counter - 1) elem xs
```

Comment: Is the code working as expected? It seems that the person that down voted the question felt that it didn't because of the statement `pieceAt on line 194 throws an error when it's called on an empty square.` I'm not the one that down voted so I can't be sure of there reasoning.

Comment: Yes it works as expected as I always check if the square is filled before calling pieceAt.